# Parallel vs Sequential naïve quick sort

Tags: c++, quicksort, c++20

I am trying to implement quicksort which runs partition sorting in parallel as given below:

```
// Returns patition points as pair
template<typename ExPo, std::random_access_iterator I, std::sentinel_for<I> S,
    class Comp = std::ranges::less, class Proj = std::identity >
    requires std::sortable<I, Comp, Proj>
    std::pair<I, I> parition_points(ExPo policy, I first, S last, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {})
{
    auto val = *std::next(first, std::distance(first, last) / 2);
    auto mid1 = std::partition(policy, first, last, [&](const auto& cur) { return  std::invoke(comp, std::invoke(proj, cur), std::invoke(proj, val)); }); // a < b
    auto mid2 = std::partition(policy, mid1, last, [&](const auto& cur)  { return !std::invoke(comp, std::invoke(proj, val), std::invoke(proj, cur)); }); // !(b < a)-> b >=a
    return { mid1, mid2 };
}

// Quick sort
template<typename ExPo, std::random_access_iterator I, std::sentinel_for<I> S,
    class Comp = std::ranges::less, class Proj = std::identity >
    requires std::sortable<I, Comp, Proj>
    void quicksort(ExPo policy, I first, S last, Comp comp = {}, Proj proj = {})
{
    if (first == last) return;
    const auto& [mid1, mid2] = parition_points(policy, first, last, std::ref(comp), std::ref(proj));
    quicksort(policy, first, mid1, std::ref(comp), std::ref(proj));
    quicksort(policy, mid2,  last, std::ref(comp), std::ref(proj));
}


int main()
{
    auto rv1 = getRandomVector(100000);
    auto rv2 = rv1;
    auto rv3 = rv1;

    // std::sort parallel
    auto sort1 = [&rv1]() { std::sort(std::execution::par, rv1.begin(), rv1.end());};
    execute(sort1);

    // quicksort in parallel 
    auto sort2 = [&rv2]() {quicksort(std::execution::par, rv2.begin(), rv2.end()); };
    execute(sort2);

    // quicksort in sequential 
    auto sort3 = [&rv3]() {quicksort(std::execution::seq, rv3.begin(), rv3.end()); };
    execute(sort3);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is godbolt compiler explorer [link](https://godbolt.org/z/jKGvK8a1e) to my example.

I was expecting better performance when calling std::partition with parallel execution policy but instead it was more or less similar or in some cases worse.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1) if your data is already effectively sorted quicksort is n^2, 2) how much data are you testing with? Threads are expensive to spin up, so the speed you achieve needs to exceed that spinup time for this to make sense.

Comment: I have test with range of data from 1000 till 1million.  I am generating sequence randomly, it is highly unlikely that it will be sorted. You could use https://godbolt.org/z/1drMx191T to check.

Comment: Your CPU may have many cores, but you have one memory. In algorithms like this, the single main memory and single main cache becomes the bottleneck. If there's something you can do to take advantage of the individual CPU caches, there maybe some advantage. Maybe you can adjust the sizes ?

Comment: @SumitJha FWIW you have an issue in your `execute` method, you're doing console IO in the timing block. That has massive variance and may affect your outcomes.

Comment: Are you sure that your implementation supports parallel algorithms? For instance, it still seems that libstdc++ does not have its own implementation and uses Intel TBB as a backend.

Comment: Anyway, your quicksort implementation is quite naive. For instance, efficient implementation typically switch to insertion sort for small blocks (lower levels of recursive tree; while only one insertion sort pass is enough at the end). Also, they use tail-call elimination while processing the longer subsequence in the loop. Moreover, they can effectively deal with worst-case scenarios. Parallel quicksort also usually uses sequential (single-threaded) sort (such as `std::sort`) once the subsequence becomes small enough. You also need to "map" threads to recursive calls effectively. Etc...

Comment: I would recommend to study parallel quicksort from the libstdc++ parallel mode. It is built upon OpenMP, but you can learn a lot from it. Look [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/parallel) for `quicksort` and `partition` headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you cannot use godbolt to demonstrate speedup (or slowdown) due to parallelism. Last time I checked, the service was giving each program one hardware thread.

Second, by default `gcc` does not do any parallelisation. There are two parallelism backends there, and the one that is used by default is called, surprisingly, "serial backend". The one that does real parallelisation is called "TBB backend" and you need to have Intel TBB library installed in order to use it.

Last but not least, this particular implementation of "parallel quicksort" is no good at all. It only tries to run std::partition in parallel, which doesn't do much, if anything. A real parallel quicksort will run *the two recursive calls to quicksort* in parallel, and of course it would not create any more threads than the hardware can support, because it's just pure overhead with zero gain.

I was able to quickly-and-dirty tweak your code such that the parallel version is actually faster. This involves something like

```
  static std::atomic<int> tc = 1;

  if (!std::is_same_v<ExPo,std::execution::parallel_policy> || last-first<32 || tc >= 8)
  {
      const auto& [mid1, mid2] = parition_points(std::execution::seq, first, last, std::ref(comp), std::ref(proj));
      quicksort(std::execution::seq, first, mid1, std::ref(comp), std::ref(proj));
      quicksort(std::execution::seq, mid2,  last, std::ref(comp), std::ref(proj));
  }
  else
  {
      ++tc;
      const auto& [mid1, mid2] = parition_points(policy, first, last, std::ref(comp), std::ref(proj));
      auto fut = std::async(std::launch::async, [&](){quicksort(policy, first, mid1, std::ref(comp), std::ref(proj));});
      quicksort(policy, mid2,  last, std::ref(comp), std::ref(proj));
      fut.wait();
      --tc;
  }
```

The performance is still quite abysmal but some gain from parallelism can be demonstrated.

Comment: I checked it on my side your version and understood why the parallel version of my naïve quicksort was not performing better. Much appreciated answer.  Thank you for insight and time.